# How to Convert H265 (go pro, 4K, 60) to DnxHQx (DnxHD 4k, 60) using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codecs

I have been trying to convert H265 to DnxHqx (DnxHD ,UHD) using ffmpeg (v. 2.8.15) in ubuntu 16. After some digging and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907398/how-to-convert-a-video-with-ffmpeg-into-the-dnxhd-dnxhr-format) answer, I wrote the following :

```
ffmpeg -i  GH010689.MP4 -c:v dnxhd -profile:v dnxhr_hqx  -vf "scale=3840:2160,fps=60000/1001,format=yuv422p" -b:v 208M -c:a pcm_s16le ~/Desktop/test.mov
```

However, I get the following errors :

```
1)Timecode frame rate 29/1 not supported
2)Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'dnxhr_hqx'
3)Unable to parse option value "dnxhr_hqx"
4)Error setting option profile to value dnxhr_hqx. 
5)Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: 1. Change `yuv422p` to `yuv422p10le`. 2. Update your ffmpeg from [here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (or follow [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)). 3. If it still fails provide the new command and the complete log from the command.